# How to pass parameter in mapActions in vuex

Tags: vuex, vuejs3

I want to pass the parameter in mapAction in the computed property.

just like we can pass parameter in mounted.

```
this.$store.dispatch('GET_SUB_CATEGORIES', this.$store.getters.GET_BUSINESS_INFO.category_id)
```

I want to send parameter with mapAction

```
computed: {
   ...mapActions(['GET_SUB_CATEGORIES', ]),
},
```

in the computed property.

Answer (score 0):

It's preety straight forward.

```
mutations: {
    yourMutation (state, payload) {
      state.yourParameter = payload
    }
  },
  actions: {
    mapThis (context, payload) {
      context.commit('yourMutation', payload)
    }
  }
```

Comment: I want to pass a parameter from the computed property in the component.

Comment: from the store?

Comment: No, from component in computed property

Comment: I didn't quite get that.. would you carry on to explain with an example?